# Can I log custom exception properties?

Tags: log4net

I have some custom exceptions that inherit from Exception that have custom properties

e.g.

```
[Serializable]
public class MyException : Exception
{
    public MyException(string message, string myProperty)
    {
        MyProperty = myProperty
    }

    public string MyProperty {get; set;}
}
```

I'd like to automatically add each custom property to my log4net logs.  Is there any built in way to do this or do I need to create some kind of custom appender?

Answer (score 2):

You can add custom fields to log4net using `GlobalContext.Properties`, like so:

```
GlobalContext.Properties["MyProperty"] = customException.MyProperty;
```

Then, in your appender configuration, you can access this custom field with `%property{MyProperty}`.

Comment: Can I use it with `XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could override the .ToString() method in your custom exception and append the output to the base .ToString() method.